Calculating volume remaining in half-cylinder shaped tank
The tank is shaped as follows:
It's a half-cylinder stacked on top of a cuboid that's stacked on an identical half-cylinder, so the two faces of the half-cylinders are facing towards the cuboid.
My father would like to be able to calculate the volume of oil remaining in the tank by measuring the distance from the top of the tank to the surface of the liquid. The difficulty, of course, is that the width of the tank varies with height in the half-cylinder portion. Once the cuboid section is reached, it is of course trivial and in the bottom half-cylinder portion it will be a symmetrical problem. So let's focus on the first half-cylinder. We measure $ h \in [0; h_0] $ from the bottom surface of the half-cylinder, h_0 = r = radius of the half-cylinder, w is the width at a given height, d is the depth. We have
\begin{equation}
\Delta V = \int_{h_0}^{h} dh' \frac{\partial V}{\partial h'} = \int_{h_0}^{h} dh' w(h') d
\end{equation}
Further $ tan(\alpha) = \frac{h}{w/2} $. Thus $ w(h) = \frac{2h}{tan(\alpha(h))} $ I was not 100% sure, but I think $ \alpha $ relates to $ \frac{h}{h_0} $ as follows: $ \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{h}{h_0} $. Thus
\begin{equation}
\Delta V = d \int_{h_0}^{h} dh' \frac{2h'}{tan(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{h'}{h_0})}
\end{equation}
I performed a variable substitution $ u := \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{h'}{h_0} $. Thus
\begin{equation}
\Delta V = \frac{8dh_0^{2}}{\pi^{2}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{h}{h_0}} du \frac{u}{tan(u)}
\end{equation}
There doesn't seem to be a neat solution for this integral. Maybe it would help to incorporate that we're only considering values of u from 0 to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $. Or maybe someone is smart enough to figure out a better way that has an easy analytical solution. I'm surprised this is this hard.

The area of a circle of radius r with origin at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ to height h from bottom  is
$$A(h)= \int_{-r}^{h-r} \sqrt{ r^2 - y^2}\ dy =r^2\  \int_{-r}^{h-r} \sqrt{ 1 - \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)^2}\ \frac{dy}{r} = =r^2\  \int_{-1}^{\frac{h}{r}-1} \sqrt{ 1 - \eta^2}\ d\eta  $$
With $\eta(\xi) =\cos(\xi)$ its a standard integral of $\sin ^2$ solved by  integration by parts twice.
